# moodle webservice(mod_quiz_save_attempt) is no longer working

Tags: moodle, moodle-api

I am working on a project where i am using moodle quiz feature. and I am  using below mentioned webservice all are working but except (mod_quiz_save_attempt)

mod_quiz_start_attempt    // working and getting response correctly

mod_quiz_save_attempt    // not working from yesterday , but getting response without any error

.
.
. etc

**Reponse of 'mod_quiz_save_attempt'   webservice:**

```
{
"status": true,
"warnings": []
}
```

But answers are not saving into the database

Any help please.

Comment: @wp78de I'm using 3.5+ version . yeah before It was working means , I'm not getting what changes i made.  and also i checked once again https://docs.moodle.org/36/en/Using_web_services

Comment: @wp78de any updates please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The problem is solved.**

The problem was in database, 'uniqueid' is not same as 'attemptid' in the table 'mod_quiz_attempts' so because of id mismatch answers were not saving.

[image]

please go through below mentioned tables which are related to the problem

*'mod_quiz_attempts'*

*'mod_question_attempts'*

*'mod_question_attempt_steps'*

*'mod_question_attempt_step_data'*

*'mod_question_usages'*

Check all tables which are mentioned above to find the solution for this problem.
I hope this answer may help if u face the same anytime.